# Compare two json with key "label" and return new json with identical objects

Tags: javascript

Here adding two json dataOne and dataTwo

```
"dataOne"=[
   {
      "label":"statusOne",
      "options":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"sometext",
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"sometext",
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "label":"statusThree",
      "options":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"sometext",
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"sometext",
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

compare with dataTwo Json "label"

```
"dataTwo" =[
   {
      "label":"statusOne",
      "options":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"some text",
            "checked":false
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"some text",
            "checked":false
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "label":"statusTwo",
      "options":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"some text",
            "checked":false
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"some text",
            "checked":false
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "label":"statusThree",
      "options":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"some text",
            "checked":false
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"some text",
            "checked":false
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "name":"some text",
            "checked":false
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

expected output:

```
"dataTwo"=[
   {
      "label":"statusOne",
      "options":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"sometext",
            "checked":true
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"sometext",
            "checked":true
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "label":"statusThree",
      "options":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"sometext",
            "checked":true
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"sometext",
            "checked":true
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: You can make use of any loop logic to achieve this. What have you attempted till now and where you are stuck with?

Comment: What is your code ? What did you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the entries in `dataOne` and compare the `label` for each entry with the `label` for each entry in `dataTwo`. If there's a match, you can add that entry to a new array.

```js
let matches = []

dataOne.forEach(entry => {
  dataTwo.forEach(entry2 => {
    if (entry.label === entry2.label) {
      entry.options.forEach(option => {
        option.checked = true
      })
      matches.push(entry)
    }
  }
})
```

Alternatively, you can use a [reduce function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const matches = dataOne.reduce((matches, entry) => {
  dataTwo.forEach(entry2 => {
    if (entry.label === entry2.label) {
      matches.push(entry);
    }
  })
  return matches
}, [])
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me but i need to match options id's and checked to true

Comment: @vinays When you find a matching label, you can instead push an object that contains the label and the options set to true. Updated my first code snippet with an example

Comment: I handled that it is working fine now Thank you

Comment: @vinays That's great to hear. If you wouldn't mind, marking my answer as best answer will close this question and I would appreciate the credit :)